# Using LINQ, can I verify a property has the same value for all objects?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Crate object, which has a List of KeyValuePairs.  Currently, I'm iterating through each pair to see if the kvp.Value.PixelsWide are the same for all items in the List.  If they are, return true, else false.

The existing method that I have is shown below:

```
public bool Validate(Crate crate)
    {
        int firstSectionWidth = 0;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, SectionConfiguration> kvp in crate.Sections)
        {
            if (firstSectionWidth == 0)//first time in loop
            {
                firstSectionWidth = kvp.Value.PixelsWide;
            }
            else //not the first time in loop
            {
                if (kvp.Value.PixelsWide != firstSectionWidth)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

I'm curious if this would be possible to execute in a LINQ query?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I believe this would work:

```
public bool Validate(Crate crate)
{
    return crate.Sections
                .Select(x => x.Value.PixelsWide)
                .Distinct()
                .Count() < 2;
}
```

This will return true if `crate.Sections` is empty as well as when the elements are all the same (which is the behavior of your current function).

Comment: This did exactly what I needed, and accounted for the case where the collection was empty.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: An elegant solution. But Distinct() forces an iteration on all items and some kind of sort internally. If you know the list has few items, its ok. If the list is big or the Validate method is intensively used, you should try Stecya's sugestion.

Comment: @AntonioR While it would, of course, iterate over all of them (`Count` makes sure of that), I would hope the internal operation of the `Distinct` operator wouldn't vary too much from Jon Skeet's reimplementation of it: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/30/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-14-distinct.aspx

Comment: +1 @AntonioR, Thanks for your input, the items that I will be iterating through will only be about 5 or 6.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 18):

Try this

```
var pixelsWide = rate.Sections.Values.First().PixelsWide;
bool result = crate.Sections.Values.All(x => x.PixelsWide == pixelsWide);
```

Comment: Throws an exception if there are no items.

Comment: Than check if there is no items and return `false`

Comment: Per Yuriy, change to `rate.Sections.Values.Select(x => x.PixelsWide).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Hmm, would be great as an extension method, something like: IEnumerable<>.AllSame(propertyName)

Answer (score 9):

Here's a variation on [Stecya's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478681/using-linq-can-i-verify-a-property-has-the-same-value-for-all-objects/5478708#5478708) answer that doesn't throw an exception for an empty collection.

```
var first = crate.Sections.Values.FirstOrDefault();
bool result = crate.Sections.Values.All(x => x.PixelsWide == first.PixelsWide);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind iterating through entire collection:

```
bool hasOneValue = crate.Sections.Select(s => s.Value.PixelsWide).Distinct().Count() == 1;
```

Or making it consistent with your code:

```
bool validateResult = crate.Sections.Select(s => s.Value.PixelsWide).Distinct().Count() <= 1;
```

Comment: Returns strange answer if there are no items.

Comment: It is not strange. I named it `hasOneValue`. `no items` doesn't has one value.

Comment: This is bad, as it does way more work than necessary. Not only does it iterate the whole collection, but it creates a `Set<T>` containing every existing value, and then iterates over that to count the values, only to compare the result to 1.

Comment: @Gabe, agree, but until we say `optimization` here I would prefer this approach because (IMO) it's more readable than other approaches with `All` or smth like that.

Answer (score 2):

Is grouping too slow?

```
public bool Validate(Crate crate)
{
    return crate.GroupBy(c => c.Value.PixelsWide).Count() < 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm with @Stecya:

```
public class Crate
{
    IList<KeyValuePair<string,SectionConfiguration>> Sections ;

    public bool IsValid()
    {
        return Sections.All( x => x.Value.PixelsWide == Sections.FirstOrDefault().Value.PixelsWide ) ;
    }

    public class SectionConfiguration
    {
        public int PixelsWide ;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My version:

```
public bool Validate(Crate crate)
{
    return !crate.Sections
           .Any(a => crate.Sections
                     .Where(b => b.Value.PixelsWide != a.Value.PixelsWide).Any()
           );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented as an extension method fairly trivially:

```
public static bool AllEqual<T1, T2>(this IEnumerable<T1> enumerable, Func<T1, T2> selector)
{
    using (var enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
            return false;

        var first = selector(enumerator.Current);
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            var current = selector(enumerator.Current);
            if (current == null)
            {
                if (first == null)
                    continue;

                return false;
            }

            if (current.Equals(first) == false)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My extension method for this looks like this:

```
public static bool AllAre<T>(this IList<T> self, Func<T, T, bool> predicate)
{
    if (self.Count == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    var first = self.First();
    return self.All(arg => predicate(arg, first));
}
```

And it is used like this:

```
myList.AllAre((x, first) => x.Value == first.Value);
```